# Unable to update state with data from an external API

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

im working on a project and i need to store fetched data from an API inside a state but it returns CORS, however, the data is succesfully fetched when i only console.log it :

```
function App() {

  const [search, setSearch] = useState('');

 useEffect(() => {
    const APIcall = async () => {
      if(search === '') return;

     
      const key = '5fce48978e1c410d4cc98624'
      const url = 'https://thisapi.io/data/api'

      const response = await fetch(`${url}/tag/${search}/post?&limit=10`, { headers: { 'app-id': key, }  });
      const result = await response.json();

      console.log(result.data)

    }

    APIcall();
  }, [search])
```

but when i try to update my search state with this data i get "from origin 'http://localhost:3000' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: Redirect is not allowed for a preflight request." error, i tried using the alternative proxy CORS anywhere but still isn't working

```
function App() {

  const [search, setSearch] = useState('');

 useEffect(() => {
    const APIcall = async () => {
      if(search === '') return;

      const resultsPerPage = 30;
      const key = '5fce48978e1c410d4cc98624'
      const url = 'https://thisapi.io/data/api'

      const response = await fetch(`${url}/tag/${search}/post?&limit=10`, { headers: { 'app-id': key, }  });
      const result = await response.json();

      setSearch(result.data)

    }

    APIcall();
  }, [search])
```

Answer (score -1):

I am not sure about you case, without access to you console, but try this:

```
const response = await fetch(`${url}/tag/${search}/post?&limit=10`, { 
  headers: { 'app-id': key, },
  mode: 'no-cors',
  credentials: 'omit'  
});
```

Comment: i tried it and now it shows me "Unhandled Rejection (SyntaxError): Unexpected end of input" tried to update the state again without it and went to network tab on my console and its constantly making requests, i cant grasp my head around why that's happening

Comment: "its constantly making requests" - You useEffect function is depend on search state: useEffect(() => {/*...*/}, [search]), this is means, that it is called every time, when search is changed and if I understands right, it is changed after each request, so, looks like my solution works )

Comment: for right handle Unhandled Rejection, you should add catch block to fetch promise (wrap it in try/catch block, or use catch method)